# JSON elements parsing into oracle column

Tags: json, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I have a oracle table where one column has JSON data. I need to extract two elements from the data and want to display as column.

I am adding JSON data as a code sample to test.

```
create table TEST_TABLE
(id number,
importdata clob);  


insert into TEST_TABLE values (100,'{"ClassId":30074,"Attributes":[{"Name":"TYPE-SPEC","Value":"SJ;3;1"},{"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},{"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"},{"Name":"GEO_METHOD","Value":"96"},{"Name":"HPRCSN","Value":2.7676}]}');
insert into TEST_TABLE values (101,'{"ClassId":30074,"Attributes":[{"Name":"TYPE-SPEC","Value":"SJ;3;1"},{"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},{"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"},{"Name":"HPRCSN","Value":3.04}]}');
insert into TEST_TABLE values (102,'{"ClassId":30074,"Attributes":[{"Name":"TYPE-SPEC","Value":"SJ;3;1"},{"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},{"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"},{"Name":"GEO_METHOD","Value":"96"},{"Name":"HPRCSN","Value":77.1814}]}');
insert into TEST_TABLE values (103,'{"ClassId":30074,"Attributes":[{"Name":"TYPE-SPEC","Value":"SJ;3;1"},{"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},{"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"},{"Name":"GEO_METHOD","Value":"-1"},{"Name":"HPRCSN","Value":3.1121}]}');
insert into TEST_TABLE values (105,'{"ClassId":32000,"Attributes":[{"Name":"ID","Value":"69804"},{"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},{"Name":"HPRCSN","Value":"5"}]},{"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"} ');
insert into TEST_TABLE values (106,'{"ClassId":32000,"Attributes":[{"Name":"ID","Value":"73576"},{"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},{"Name":"HPRCSN","Value":"5"}]},{"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"}]} ');
insert into TEST_TABLE values (107,'{"ClassId":32000,"Attributes":[{"Name":"ID","Value":"73589"},{"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},{"Name":"HPRCSN","Value":"5"}]},{"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"}]} ');
insert into TEST_TABLE values (108,'{"ClassId":32000,"Attributes":[{"Name":"ID","Value":"74015"},{"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},{"Name":"HPRCSN","Value":"5"}]},{"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"}]} ');
commit;
```

Now my actual plan was to get two elements out of these data : HMETH and HPRCSN.
I want to write a sql which will give me the output like this.

[image]

But I faced two problem

1. Each elements position might not same for each row. So i cannot use fixed position for
   substr for that.
2. If the Value of HPRCSN is round then it has "" enclosed and if it is decimal then it comes without "". so all decimal output comes as round integer.

We made some code which is working some of it, but not 100% working because elements position and the decimal values. If anyone have any suggestion to fix this sql it would be so helpful.

```
 select t1.id
,to_number(regexp_substr(replace(regexp_replace(importdata, '[^,[:digit:]]',''),',,',','),'[^,]+',15)) as HMETH
,to_number(regexp_substr(replace(regexp_replace(importdata, '[^,[:digit:]]',''),',,',','),'[^,]+',18)) as HPRCSN
from TEST_TABLE t1;
```

Here is my output which is wrong for some rows because of the position.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use regular expressions to parse [<s>HTML</s>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1509264) JSON; use a proper parser.

---

You can use `JSON_TABLE` to extract the name-value pairs:

```
select id,
       classid,
       name,
       value
from   TEST_TABLE t1
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t1.importdata,
         '$'
         COLUMNS (
           classid NUMBER PATH '$.ClassId',
           NESTED PATH '$.Attributes[*]' COLUMNS (
             name  VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.Name',
             value VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.Value'
           )
         )
       );
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

| ID | CLASSID | NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 30074 | TYPE-SPEC | SJ;3;1 |
| 100 | 30074 | HREF | -1 |
| 100 | 30074 | HMETHOD | 96 |
| 100 | 30074 | GEO_METHOD | 96 |
| 100 | 30074 | HPRCSN | 2.7676 |
| 101 | 30074 | TYPE-SPEC | SJ;3;1 |
| 101 | 30074 | HREF | -1 |
| 101 | 30074 | HMETHOD | 96 |
| 101 | 30074 | HPRCSN | 3.04 |
| 102 | 30074 | TYPE-SPEC | SJ;3;1 |
| 102 | 30074 | HREF | -1 |
| 102 | 30074 | HMETHOD | 96 |
| 102 | 30074 | GEO_METHOD | 96 |
| 102 | 30074 | HPRCSN | 77.1814 |
| 103 | 30074 | TYPE-SPEC | SJ;3;1 |
| 103 | 30074 | HREF | -1 |
| 103 | 30074 | HMETHOD | 96 |
| 103 | 30074 | GEO_METHOD | -1 |
| 103 | 30074 | HPRCSN | 3.1121 |
| 105 | 32000 | ID | 69804 |
| 105 | 32000 | HREF | -1 |
| 105 | 32000 | HPRCSN | 5 |
| 106 | 32000 | ID | 73576 |
| 106 | 32000 | HREF | -1 |
| 106 | 32000 | HPRCSN | 5 |
| 107 | 32000 | ID | 73589 |
| 107 | 32000 | HREF | -1 |
| 107 | 32000 | HPRCSN | 5 |
| 108 | 32000 | ID | 74015 |
| 108 | 32000 | HREF | -1 |
| 108 | 32000 | HPRCSN | 5 |

If you want the values in columns (instead of rows) then use `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  select id,
         classid,
         name,
         value
  from   TEST_TABLE t1
         CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
           t1.importdata,
           '$'
           COLUMNS (
             classid NUMBER PATH '$.ClassId',
             NESTED PATH '$.Attributes[*]' COLUMNS (
               name  VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.Name',
               value VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.Value'
             )
           )
         ) j
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(value) FOR name IN (
    'ID' AS idvalue,
    'HREF' AS href,
    'GEO_METHOD' AS geomethod,
    'HPRCSN' AS hprcsn,
    'HMETHOD' AS hmethod
  )
);
```

Which outputs:

| ID | CLASSID | IDVALUE | HREF | GEOMETHOD | HPRCSN | HMETHOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 30074 | *null* | -1 | 96 | 2.7676 | 96 |
| 107 | 32000 | 73589 | -1 | *null* | 5 | *null* |
| 108 | 32000 | 74015 | -1 | *null* | 5 | *null* |
| 101 | 30074 | *null* | -1 | *null* | 3.04 | 96 |
| 106 | 32000 | 73576 | -1 | *null* | 5 | *null* |
| 103 | 30074 | *null* | -1 | -1 | 3.1121 | 96 |
| 105 | 32000 | 69804 | -1 | *null* | 5 | *null* |
| 102 | 30074 | *null* | -1 | 96 | 77.1814 | 96 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Oi2Rixlk?hide=12)

Comment: Wonderful. that is exactly what we are looking for. JASON TABLE is a function or some oracle default parser i guess? thanks for the suggestion, we used reg exp just to have some output from the text. but was not sure how we can manage everything. thanks for the help.